# How can you check the value of a metric in vetor.dev unit tests

Tags: vector-vrl

When testing Vector log_to_metric transformations, how can a unit test validate the metric count?

I've been able to validate the tags, kind and metric name, but for an incremental metric (a counter), I've not been able to validate the count with:

`.counter.value`, `.counter` or `.value`. All of these come out as null when checked in the unit test VRL.

This is despite the JSON dump in the failed vector test showing a clear value:

```
output payloads from ["my_event_counter"] (events encoded as JSON):
  {"name":"my_event_counter","tags":{"entity":"interesting","system":"my_system"},"timestamp":"2022-09-08T10:30:58.173920Z","kind":"incremental","counter":{"value":1.0}}
```

Comment: Although this might not be relevant to you anymore - I suggest you add an example of your test and maybe a simplified version of your transformation, it would make it easier for someone to help figure out what's wrong.